# Building a line chart using fs.createReadStream on d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have this lines of code, which reads in a basic CSV file:

```js
const d3 = require("d3");
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const fs = require('fs');
const results = [];

fs.createReadStream('d3Vis\\mock_pdp_ice.csv', 'utf-8')
    .pipe(csv(["ShapValues", "Margin"]))
    .on('data', (data) => results.push(data))
    .on('end', function () {
        console.log(results);
    });
```

I am trying to build a line chart from this, but I am getting a blank screen when loading the HTML file in browser. How do I build a graph from this after reading in my file?